# Regular expression to match Azure load balancer name

Tags: regex, azure

How can I validate azure load balancer name using regex?

The [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftnetwork) are:

- Can contain alphanumerics, underscores, periods, and hyphens.
- Start with alphanumeric.
- End with alphanumeric or underscore.
- Lenght between 1-80 (inclusive)

I tried using `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.-]{1,80}$`, but it matches strings that ends with period, strings with 81 characters and doesn't match strings with only 1 character.

Comment: One way would be `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_.-]{0,79}(?<=[A-Za-z0-9_])$` if Lookbehinds are supported. A shorter version that also supports Unicode: `^[^\W_][\w.-]{0,79}(?<=\w)$`.

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,78}[A-Za-z0-9_])?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried  matches at least 2 chars as this part `[A-Za-z0-9]` matches a single char and this part `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]{1,80}` matches at least 1 char which can match 81 chars in total max.

---

You could start the match with an alphanumeric char, then optionally match 0-78 chars matching one of `[A-Za-z0-9.-]` and end the match with `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so it can end with an underscore as well.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,78}[A-Za-z0-9_])?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` Match a single alphanumeric
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,78}` Match 0-78 repetitions of any of the listed allowed chars
  - `[A-Za-z0-9_]` Match a single alphanumeric or underscore
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QV64q9/1)

If you don't want to match consecutive hyphens or dots, you might also use

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9_.-]{1,80}$)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:[.-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLhk9n/1)

Comment: Should it be "^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9._-]{0,78}[A-Za-z0-9_])?$"?, since it can also contain underscore in the middle of a string.

Comment: @QiongKaiYe Yes,iIn that case you can add the underscore to the character class.